# I finished filling out my husband's DS-260 application but I am stuck where they ask you to sign a selective service form

Tags: visa

The red box is what I don’t understand

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what you (or your husband) don't understand?

Comment: The US doesn't actually have a draft for military service but the requirement to register for it has for some reason persisted.  I have lost track of the current situation, but that's the form they're referring to.

Comment: @LorenPechtel it hasn't so much persisted as been revived.  Registration ended in 1975, a couple of weeks after the final draft lottery but a couple of years after the last actual conscription, the volunteer military having been announced in 1973.  Draft registration was revived in 1980.  The reinstatement of draft registration was difficult to miss for men born in the 1960s.  A fairly detailed account is available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_Service_System

Comment: I've voted to close as "needing details or clarity."  I suppose there's a good question in here, but without knowing why you're "stuck," we can't know what to say that might help you become unstuck.

Comment: And then I went in to fix the punctuation/capitalization and saw that there was an orphaned image link.  This helps to clarify the question, so I've retracted the close vote.

Comment: @phoog But that doesn't say what the current status of the rule is.  A check with Google seems to show it's still required.

Comment: @LorenPechtel what's still required?  What rule did you check?

Answer (score 5):

The red box is telling you, or rather your husband, that you have to have to open and read DS-1810 before signing.  DS-1810 is a notice informing the immigrant visa applicant that men aged from 18 to 25 must register with the selective service system within 30 days of arriving in the US (or before their 26th birthday if that comes first).

The point here is for the applicant to acknowledge that he is aware of this requirement.  The actual registration does not take place until after the applicant immigrates to the US (or, if the applicant is over 26 at the time of immigration, there is no registration).

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that (contrary to the question's title), the OP is not being asked to _sign_ the selective service form - merely read it.

Comment: it doesn’t let me sign it…and i can’t submit application not sure why the button doesn’t let me submit

Comment: @AshleyCaballero what can't you sign?  The DS-1810 or the DS-260?